# Silverstripe: SS_DAG_CyclicException. DAG has cyclic requirements

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have just upgraded a couple of sites from an earlier release of SS3 to the 3.0 stable build (CMS and Sapphire). Now, when I try to dev/build I am getting the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'SS_DAG_CyclicException' with message 'DAG has cyclic requirements' in /Users/fraser/Documents/Work/HallPass/sapphire/core/DAG.php:73
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/fraser/Documents/Work/HallPass/sapphire/core/manifest/ConfigManifest.php(272): SS_DAG->sort()
#1 /Users/fraser/Documents/Work/HallPass/sapphire/core/manifest/ConfigManifest.php(144): SS_ConfigManifest->sortYamlFragments()
#2 /Users/fraser/Documents/Work/HallPass/sapphire/core/manifest/ConfigManifest.php(75): SS_ConfigManifest->regenerate(false)
#3 /Users/fraser/Documents/Work/HallPass/sapphire/core/Core.php(275): SS_ConfigManifest->__construct('/Users/fraser/D...', false, false)
#4 /Users/fraser/Documents/Work/HallPass/sapphire/main.php(62): require_once('/Users/fraser/D...')
#5 {main}
  thrown in /Users/fraser/Documents/Work/HallPass/sapphire/core/DAG.php on line 73
```

Everything else works fine however, it's just when I do anything in /dev. I have made some changes and need to regenerate the manifest on these sites.

I have also tried a clean install of SS and am getting the same issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: what exact version of silverstripe are you using?
have you tried a completely clean install (no custom code at all)?

Comment: As noted in the post, I had tried a clean install yes. This was with the lastest stable build of 3.0. It turned out to be a bug in the release. See bug #7817 on open.silverstripe.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the CMS and Sapphire code. I raised the issue on open.silverstripe.org and it has since been corrected. #7817 on open.silverstripe.org

Comment: so your problem has been fixed? if so please mark this question as answered